# Ugly "Next Privilege" text on user activity page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, privileges

It seems "See votes, expandable user card" goes on a second line on the activity page of the user profile resulting in a pretty bad look:

[image]

You can see it live on [this profile](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/1655/tim?tab=topactivity) (though of course that may change any day now depending on their rep-growth).

I'm using Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Repro in Firefox 60.0.1 (64-bit).

Comment: Seems to be the case in every user I see (including myself) that has the next privilege tracked (not their next badge) and have less than 25K reps on the site (so there is still a next privilege)

Comment: Repro on Edge 42.17134.1.0.

Comment: I don't believe the bar height is correct either.

Comment: Changing the `min-height` attribute of the `.s-progress` CSS class from `4px` to something more reasonable like `25px` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Reproduced Vivaldi 1.15, also reproduced IE11

Comment: duplicate of [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371818/milestone-information-overlapping-other-text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371818/milestone-information-overlapping-other-text)

Comment: The problem is the status bar is not getting its proper height and padding applied, but it seems based on the moderator tag that they are aware and working on a fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. We recently updated our progress bar styles and the privilege progress bar styles weren't correctly updated. This has been corrected now.

[image]

Comment: It looks like all privileges except "See votes, expandable usercard" are centered (see the link in my original question). Should I open another question for this?

Comment:  Seems to be an issue with the icon size. I'll take a further look.

Comment: Looks good now. Thanks Hynes!!