# Sizing issue for next-privilege progress bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

We recently had a bug in the next-privilege tracker on the profile page. The progress bar was really thin, but it looks like that's [been fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313434/ugly-next-privilege-text-on-user-activity-page).

However, a new problem seems to have emerged: the outline of the bar is larger than the colored region on my most recently created profiles. It's only visible when I'm looking at my own profile: it's not visible not when I'm signed out and I don't observe it when I'm looking at other users' profiles. I was able to observe it only on sites I joined today (both beta sites like engineering (and 3D printing) and themed sites like Puzzling). It does not show up on sites which I joined earlier but maintained inactive accounts on: I have had a Chemistry SE account for a while but I have never posted or voted (or done anything else) using that account, yet this problem doesn't appear there.

This is what it looks like
[image]

The way I observed this:

- Find a site where I don't have an account and I've never tried to do anything at all, create an account by clicking "Join this community" (top-right corner)
- Immediately view my own profile, click "track next privilege" when it tells me
  that I can edit community wikis.
- Visiting the profile again, after closing and reopening the tab, the problem does not go away.

As you can see, the colored portion of the privilege tracker is really small. I observed it while being signed in (looking at my own profile) on both Google Chrome (latest build for windows 10) and Brave (latest build, windows 10).

It looks like the problem is that the whole bar is too tall; when I viewed it without being signed in, the bar was thinner. Can this be fixed? It's not particularly commonly seen: it may disappear once I post something and get a 'top tag', but it's not very pretty.

Comment: It’s probably due to the “top tag” missing to the left of the progress bar.

Comment: @Xufox I've just added an edit asking for people who have some activity on beta/theme-less sites to add something. I have never posted on chemistry, so I don't have a top tag there, but it all looks fine there. Also, when I'm signed out, I can look at my engineering SE profile and it looks perfect. The problem is visible only when I'm signed in.

Comment: @Xufox I've just added an edit asking for people who have some activity on beta/theme-less sites to add something. I have never posted on chemistry (it's not a beta site, and it has a custom theme), so I don't have a top tag there, but it all looks fine there. Also, when I'm signed out, I can look at my engineering SE profile and it looks perfect. The problem is visible only when I'm signed in.

Comment: I cannot repro this problem when I view your profile on 3D printing. Beta communities share the same CSS as themed communities for privilege progress bars.

Comment: I don't expect it to be reproducible when you look at my profile @Hynes. I mentioned in my post that when I'm not signed in, it doesn't show up; so it should be a similar case when you're signed in with a different account and looking at someone else's profile page. I don't see the problem when I look at [this user's](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/16551/nipunasudha?tab=topactivity) page. (I chose some random user from the new-user page on engineering SE) But it's still misaligned on my own profile.

Comment: When you said that Beta communities and themed communities run on the same code, I decided to test that again. I find that on Puzzling SE, the sizing is wrong again, just like on 3D printing. Maybe it didn't show up on Chemistry because I had an inactive account earlier. That means it's showing up everywhere on accounts which I'm creating today. I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: @Hynes I think the problem occurs when the [Measure your impact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iefGK.png) box is loaded, that's why a user can see the problem on his/her profile only.

Comment: I also asked it on [puzzling.stackexchange](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/next-privilage-design-bug)